# Sprintf versus Puts in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Why does `sprintf` not output in a function, but `puts` will?

```
irb(main):001:0> 3.times {|i| sprintf("%s", i.to_s)}
=> 3
irb(main):002:0> 3.times {|i| puts i}
0
1
2
=> 3
```

The [documentation for `puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) says it goes to stdout. Why would `sprintf` not also go to stdout?

Using Ruby 2.5.0.

Comment: Because [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) is designed to format string, not to print it out.

Comment: It's a POSIX thing, `printf` family has functions with different output targets--stdout v. given file descriptor v. string. `Kernel#sprintf` is meant to mirror the string output branch of the `printf` family. https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-sprintf/

Comment: Important to note here that the first produces no output, `=>` is the way `irb` describes *return values*, and the second produces output and a return value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sprintf` returns the formatted string, rather than printing it anywhere. Check out http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf for the documentation.

You might be looking for `printf` instead.

Comment: Just a footnote, this is copied almost exactly from C. `printf` prints a formatted string, `sprintf` creates the string without printing it.